# MS Access transform statement calculated fields

Tags: ms-access

The Transform Statement:

TRANSFORM Sum(January2015.txnamount) AS SumOftxnamount
SELECT January2015.txndate2, January2015.cbsaccno
FROM January2015
GROUP BY January2015.txndate2, January2015.cbsaccno
PIVOT January2015.txntypes;

gives output as below:

```
+------------+---------------+-----+-----+
|  txndate2  |   cbsaccno    | A1  | A2  |
+------------+---------------+-----+-----+
| 01/01/2015 | 0021010392747 |  50 | 300 |
| 01/01/2015 | 0021010392891 | 100 | 200 |

+------------+---------------+-----+-----+
```

I want a fifth field (calculated field A1-A2)
which have values -250 and -100 for the sample data above.

Anyway to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the query you built (for example, PivotQuery).  Create a new query that calls PivotQuery with the following SQL:

```
SELECT PivotQuery.*, [a1]-[a2] AS CalcField
FROM PivotQuery;
```

Comment: On trying the above, I am getting "An Action query cannot be used as a row source"

Comment: It worked on closing the PivotQuery. (Earlier the PivotQuery was open).

Comment: @user1955215 where are you using the query?  If you build the two queries and run each, you should get the results you are asking for.  If you try to use this in some specific part of Access you can run into the error you are stating.  Can you give me a bigger picture of the use of these queries?